# Ghostscript: ps2pdf doesn't work with Win 7 32-bit

Tags: windows, ghostscript

I have the latest GPL Ghostscript v9.05 and I am running it on Win 32 bit systems. On my XP machine, both commands

```
ps2pdf -v -
```

and

```
rungs -v (used internally by TeXLive)
```

report of Ghostscript 9.05 being available as follows:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

On another Win 7 computer, the command

```
ps2pdf -v -
```

at the command line is **not** recognised as being a valid `ps2pdf`syntax but `rungs -v` **works fine**.

I have read on the internet about setting temporary directories for Ghostscript here:

http://schlingel.bplaced.net/?p=54

and it says basically to edit the `gssetgs.bat` file in the `lib` folder of Ghostscript and add the lines:

```
set path=%ProgramFiles%\gs\gs9.02\lib;%ProgramFiles%\gs\gs9.02\bin;%windir%\SysWOW64
set TMP=%YOUR_TEMP%
set TEMP=%TMP%
```

This needs to be modified appropriately by replacing *9.02* with *9.05* in my case. Now on Win 7, how should the last two lines regarding the temporary folder be? Can I have for `Set TMP` as follows:

```
set TMP=%"C:\Users\hihi\AppData\Local\Temp"%
```

Is it the right syntax?

I have also put the `tmp` and `temp` variables in my *Environment variables*.

**Update**

A. Using `ps2pdf`, here is how I convert a `PS` to a `PDF` file on my Win 7 machine and I get an error:

```
C:\work\misc>ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r720 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dUseFlateCompression=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dEPSCrop "%1.ps" "%1.pdf"


Unknown device:
Unrecoverable error: undefined in .uninstallpagedevice
Operand stack:
defaultdevice
```

**Note: the above command works fine on my Win XP machine!**

B. Using `gswin32c` here is how I convert a `PS` to a `PDF` file on my Win 7 machine and this **works**:

```
C:\work\misc>gswin32c.exe -o "%1.pdf" -dNOSAFER -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -r720 dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dUseFlateCompression=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dNumRenderingThreads=2 -c "60000000 setvmthreshold" -f -dEPSCrop "%1.ps"


GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Loading NimbusSanL-Regu font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu... 2837152
1454727 4413848 3026018 1 done.
Loading Dingbats font from %rom%Resource/Font/Dingbats... 2837152 1510862 457461
6 3180865 1 done.
Loading NimbusSanL-Bold font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Bold... 2857248
1553499 4655000 3251960 1 done.
```

**Note: the above command also works fine on my Win XP machine**

**To summarise**: I have problem with `ps2pdf` on my Win 7 machine.

**New (May 09, 2012)**

This is what I get when I *rem* the last two lines as Ken suggested:

```
C:\work\misc>ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -r720 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dUseFlateCompression=true -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dSubsetFonts=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dEPSCrop "%1.ps" "%1.pdf"
Unrecoverable error: typecheck in .putdeviceprops
avoiding clean up
```

The *temp* folder has those temporary files you mentioned.

The contents of `_.at`:

```
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.4 
-dNOSAFER 
-r720 
-dCompatibilityLevel
```

The contents of `_.at2`:

```
-q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE#pdfwrite 
-sOutputFile#-dUseFlateCompression 
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.4 
-dNOSAFER 
-r720 
-dCompatibilityLevel 
-c .setpdfwrite -f1.5
```

**Update May 11**

**Note: This is working fine now on my win 7 machine**

```
C:\work\misc>ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -r720 -dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 -dUseFlateCompression#true -dMaxSubsetPct#100 -dSubsetFonts#true -dEmbedAllFonts#true -dEPSCrop "defense.ps" "defense.pdf"
avoiding clean up
```

The contents of `_.at`:

```
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.4 
-dNOSAFER 
-r720 
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 
-dUseFlateCompression#true 
-dMaxSubsetPct#100 
-dSubsetFonts#true 
-dEmbedAllFonts#true 
-dEPSCrop
```

The contents of `_.at2`:

```
-q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE#pdfwrite 
-sOutputFile#"defense.pdf" 
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.4 
-dNOSAFER 
-r720 
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.5 
-dUseFlateCompression#true 
-dMaxSubsetPct#100 
-dSubsetFonts#true 
-dEmbedAllFonts#true 
-dEPSCrop 
-c .setpdfwrite -f"defense.ps"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far more likely than a temporary file problem is permissions on the directory where you are trying to write the destination file. The error message you quote occurs long before any temporary files are used, but is a very common error if you try to write to a directory which does not exist, or which the process has no write permission for.

First thing to do is post the actual gswin32 command line you are using.

The syntax you are querying is incorrect. %value% is a Windows scripting operation which says 'replace the stuff between the % signs by the named value'. So if I declare 'set VAL=c:/temp' Then I can say 'set NEWVAL=%VAL%/New' which will make NEWVAL 'c:/temp/new'. You can find more about windows scripting in the Windows help, or by a quick Google.

Given that 'ps2pdf' (which is a Windows script) can't be found on your Windows 7 machine (at least I assume that's what you mean by 'is not recognised as being a valid ps2pdf command') it does seem like you need to add the Ghostscript paths to your environment. Simply altering gssetgs.bat on its own will do nothing, you need to ensure that this script file is called from your autoexec.bat script, so that the additional environment settings are applied.

If you aren't sure what autoexec.bat is, or how to modify it, then again Google should help you pretty quickly.

Did you actually install Ghostscript, or simply copy it ?

Given that Ghostscript works correctly, the problem must be in the shell script 'ps2pdf', or more accurately some change in Windows 7 is causing the old script not to work.

This script is (unfortunately) rather more complex than I would like (I didn't write it). it actually uses about three different scripts to do the work. You really need to find out what is being sent to GS.

Probably the simplest way to do this is to edit 'ps2pdfxx.bat'. At the :end label you'll see 'rem Clean up' followed by two lines beginning 'if exist'. Put rem in front of those two. Add a line which says 'echo avoiding clean up' The end of the file should look like this:

:end
rem Clean up.
rem if exist "%TEMP%_.at" erase "%TEMP%_.at"
rem if exist "%TEMP%_.at"2 erase "%TEMP%_.at"2
echo avoiding clean up

Now run your command line (by the way you *really* don't need to put -sDEVICE= when using ps2pdf.....)

In your TEMP directory you should have files called _.at and possibly _.at2 which will contain the actual commands being sent to GS.

OK the file _.at is copied into the file *.at2, and then*.at2 is used as the list of arguments to Ghostscript. Commenting up the file you got:

---This line added by the batch file ps2pdfxx.bat
-q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE#pdfwrite

---These lines come from _.at
-sOutputFile#-dUseFlateCompression 
-dCompatibilityLevel#1.4 
-dNOSAFER 
-r720 
-dCompatibilityLevel

--This line added by the batch file ps2pdfxx.bat
-c .setpdfwrite -f1.5

There are a number of problems with this:

-sOutputFile#-dUseFlateCompression

This in effect sets the output file to '-dUseFlateCompression'

-c .setpdfwrite -f1.5

I'm not completely sure what this will do. Either it will handle the -f properly and terminate the PostScript input, or it will ignore it as an unrecognised switch (probably the latter). The '1.5' *ought* to be the input filename, without that Ghostscript doesn't know which file to use..... Even if it did, it will try to write the output to a bogus filename.

To be honest I would suggest that, if you want to set all these switches, you simply invoke Ghostscript directly rather than trying to use the script. In fact I'd recommend that anyway, every time I look at these scripts I shudder more.

Almost everything that the ps2pdf script is doing is being overridden by your command line, or is not required in the first place.

Comment: @ KenS Thanks. Yes I fully installed Ghostscript 9.05 and have the *lib* and the *bin* folders in my path and I have set the *GS_LIB* variable to point to the *lib* folder. Gswin32c.exe is recognised from the command line. I've updated my post with the information you are asking for. 1 vote up

Comment: OK the command line won't work, because you haevn't specified an output file name. Unlike the script, GS needs you to give it an explicit name. Try "gswin32c..... -sOutputFile=%1.pdf .... %1.ps' or you can use the -o switch which also includes -dNOPAUSE and -dBATCH.

Comment: @ Ken S Thanks. I have done some tests and have edited much of my post and I show what error messages I am getting. In essence, I could make `gwin32c` to work on my Win 7 machine but not `ps2pdf`. However both work equally well on my Win XP machine. I have the same installation of `Ghostscript 9.05` on both machines. I have tried to make my post clearer.

Comment: @ Ken S Thanks but I cannot *link* to what you are saying with my *ps2pdfxx.bat* file. I have updated my post so that you can see the contents of my *bat* files.

Comment: I really do mean a file called ps2pdfxx.bat, not ps2pdf14.bat. THe 'xx' are part of the filename, not a placeholder.

Comment: I need to see the content of those two temporary files. They should contain the command line invocation being used for Ghostscript and that should tell me what's going on. Maybe :-)

Comment: @ Ken S. I've now put them in the post. Hope they can tell you something.

Comment: It looks like the Windows *7* Shell command 'findstr' is catching the '=' in CompatibilityLevel=1.5. This is causing the script to stop processing the command line switches, and treat the '1.5' as the input filename. I've a feeling this is a well-known problem with Windows scripts, you should use '#' instead of '=' throughout your command line. This may solve the problem for you.

Comment: @ Ken S Finally it worked. I've heard about # but thought it was for Linux. I've updated my post with the contents of the *temporary files* and **I see that now all options are well taken**. You have been very patient with me and I have indeed learned a lot from you. Thank you very much. I hope you will get lots of up votes here for your efforts.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear its finally working for you, many thanks for letting me know, next time someone has this problem I can answer it more quickly :-)

Comment: @ Ken S You're welcome. A final comment: Does `gswin32c.exe` require `-sDEVICE=pdfwrite`? You told me eralier somewhere that `ps2pdf` does not require it.

Comment: @ Ken S. Yes one can `pdf` the `ps` inside Ghostscript but one has to choose the option `variable page size` to produce the correct `pdf`.

Comment: Yes, Gs requires -sDEVICE=pdfwrite, but ps2pdf doesn't because the batch script adds it. I'm afraid I dont understand your last comment about 'pdf the ps inside Ghostscript' though.

Comment: @ Ken S Thanks. About my last comment, sorry if I wasn't clear. I should have said `GSview` instead of `Ghostscript`. Well, I meant that instead of converting the `ps` to a `pdf` via the command line, one can also do the conversion inside `GSview` via `File > Convert > choose pdfwrite with option "Variable Page Size"`. This also works for me.

Comment: Ah, OK, understood. As I understand it, GSView normally sets a specific page size, determined from the DSC comments if present, or the default if they are not present. If you do that then you probably won't get the right answer. The default GS behaviour is to honour the media request in the document. In GSView this is your 'variable page size' and it just means 'don't specify a page size'. Please note that despite the name, GSView is owned and supported by a different organisation from Ghostscript (confusingly!)